# Topology and groupoids, proof 7.2.5 lemma.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fibration

> [Pg 269, 7.2.5 lemma](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf) Let $i:A \rightarrow X$ be a cofibration. Let $H:X \times \mathbb{I} \rightarrow Y$ be a homotopy $f \simeq g$, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a homotopy rel end maps $G=H(i \times 1)$ to a homotopy $G' : u \simeq v$. Then $H$ is homotopic rel end maps to a homotopy $H'$  such that $H'(i \times 1)=G'$.

I am struggling to understand the proof :

1. What is the purpose of this step.

   > $W$ is a retract of $Z=X \times \mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{I}$.

EDIT: From comment, the only thing we need is any map on $W$ extends to a map on $Z$. This is proven with out using the fact $W$ is a retract.

2. Why this argument works:

> $T \cong X \times \mathbb{I} \times 0$, implies $T$ and $A \times \mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{I}$ have the gluing property?

I couldn't construct the diagram chase from gluing property with $X \times \mathbb{I} \times 0$. In fact, I thought $T$ and $A \times \mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{I}$ satisfy gluing property simply being closed subspaces of their union.

Comment: if $W$ is a retract of $Z$ then any map on $W$ can be extended to a map on $Z$. That is the main reason of proving that $W$ is a retract of $Z$. First a map is specified on $T=X\times\mathbb I\times0\cup X\times0\times\mathbb I\cup X\times1\times\mathbb I$. It is shown (by means of $1\times\phi$) that $T$ and $A\times\mathbb I\times\mathbb I$ have the gluing property so that  joining of $\mathcal G$ results in a map on $A\times\mathbb I\times\mathbb I\cup T=W$. **Now** it can be applied that $W$ is a retract of $Z$: the map on $W$ can be extended to $X\times\mathbb I\times\mathbb I$.

Comment: Thanks drhab, but I don't see where he proves that $W$ is a retract of $Z$? I think he proves directly that any map on $W$ extends over to $Z$. Don't you think the retract step is unnecessary?

Comment: It is proved that $i\times1:A\times\mathbb I$ is a cofibration (using 7.2.4 corolarry 2). Then consequently any map on $A\times\mathbb I\times\mathbb I\cup X\times\mathbb I\times0=(1\times\phi)(W)$ extends over $Z$. Then also any map on $W$ extends over $Z$ since $1\times\phi$ is a homeomorphism. If $R$ is a retract of $B$ then any map on $R$ can be extended on $B$, but also the converse is true: if any map on $R$ can be extended on $B$ then $R$ is a retract of $B$. I have to go now, and will come back later.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. I guess this is how we prove it(?) : Suppose retract,
$$W \xrightarrow{i} Z \xrightarrow{r} W \xrightarrow{f} Y $$ 
For a given map $f:W \rightarrow Y$, retract $r:Z \rightarrow W$. Then we can extend by $fr$, noting $fri=f|_W=f$.  Conversely, Let $1_W : W \rightarrow W$ be identity, then extending it yields a retract.

Comment: Now after your explanation, I guess the author assumes the reader knows the equivalence (which I did not prior to your explanation :P ). Since if you read the proof, we can simply delete the line "is a retract of $Z$".

Comment: Yes, that is the way how to prove it. I think indeed that the author used the terminology "..$W$ is a retract of $Z$" as a sort of abbreviation for "..every map on $W$ can be extended over $Z$". Btw, Topology and Groupoids is a nice book.